# Javascript - upload image on website and find what is its size

Tags: javascript

I use the following code for uploading a picture and displaying it on the website:

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
        <p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
        <p><img id="output"/></p>

    <script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var image = document.getElementById('output');
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(image.clientHeight)
    };
    </script>
```

As you can see, I´m trying to find the width and height of that image. How can be this done? I was trying using both image.width / image.clientWidth but none of them worked, it always returned 0 only (or undefined).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get height and width of image in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872975/cant-get-height-and-width-of-image-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, that is helpful. Thanks :)